# Using Rust crates for an STM32 microcontroller board

Tags: rust, embedded, stm32, stm32ldiscovery, stm32l152

I'm currently trying to learn Rust (for embedded specifically), coming from a background of C for embedded systems and Python.
So far, I've been reading [Rust Programming Language](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/title-page.html) and [Rust for Embedded](https://docs.rust-embedded.org/book/), and read a few blog posts on the web.

I want my first project to be a simple "Blinky", where an LED blinks infinitely. I've got an STM32L152CDISCOVERY board with an STM32L152 chip in it (basically same as STM32L151), which is a Cortex M3.

Instead of implementing everything from scratch, I want to leverage existing crates and HALs. I've found two that seem promising: [stm32l1](https://crates.io/crates/stm32l1) and [stm32l1xx-hal](https://crates.io/crates/stm32l1xx-hal). I've tried to read the documentation of each of them and also part of the source code, but I still can't figure out how to use them correctly.

Got a few questions about Rust and about the crates:

1. I see that `stm32l1xx-hal` has a dependency on `stm32l1`. Do I need to add both as a dependency in my `Cargo.toml` file? Or will that create problems related to ownership?
2. Is this the correct way to add them? Why is the second one added like that `[dependencies.stm32l1]`?

   ```
   [dependencies]
   cortex-m-rt = "0.6.10"
   cortex-m-semihosting = "0.3.3"
   panic-halt = "0.2.0"
   stm32l1xx-hal = "0.1.0"

   [dependencies.stm32l1]
   version = "0.13.0"
   features = ["stm32l151", "rt"]
   ```
3. To blink the LD4 (which is connected to <s>PB4</s> PB6), I've got to enable the GPIOB in the RCC register and then configure the pin to push pull output. By inspecting the documentation of `stm32l1xx-hal`, I see that there is an [RCC struct](https://docs.rs/stm32l1xx-hal/0.1.0/stm32l1xx_hal/rcc/struct.Rcc.html) and a [PB4 struct](https://docs.rs/stm32l1xx-hal/0.1.0/stm32l1xx_hal/gpio/gpiob/struct.PB4.html) with the method `into_push_pull_output`. However, I still don't understand how to use these structs: how to import them or how to get an instance of them.

I've seen code examples for `stm32l1` but not for `stm32l1xx-hal`. I know that I can do this:

```
use stm32l1::{stm32l151};
...
let p = stm32l151::Peripherals::take().unwrap();
p.RCC.ahbenr.modify(|_,w| w.gpiopben().set_bit());
```

But in the source code of `stm32l1xx-hal` I see that the RCC part is already done in `impl GpioExt for $GPIOX`, but I don't know how to get to this "Parts" functionality.

Any help that points me in the right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got some help from a Discord community. The answers were (modified a bit by me):

1. `stm32l1xx-hal` already depends on `stm32l1` as [seen here](https://github.com/stm32-rs/stm32l1xx-hal/blob/master/Cargo.toml#L51). There's no need to import it twice. It is enough to add to Cargo.toml:

   ```
   [dependencies.stm32l1xx-hal]
   version = "0.1.0"
   default-features = false
   features = ["stm32l151", "rt"]
   ```

- Note that the `default-features = false` is optional, but without it the compiler was giving me an error.

2. The syntaxes are equivalent, but as I said above, I only need to add the HAL one. You can add curly braces `{}` in the first style to add the options, such as:

   ```
   stm32l1xx-hal = { version = "0.1.0", features = ["stm32l151", "rt"]}
   ```
3. The right code for doing the blinky (which was on PB6, not PB4, sigh) was:

   ```
   #![no_main]
   #![no_std]

   use panic_halt as _;

   use cortex_m_rt::entry;
   use stm32l1xx_hal::delay::Delay;
   use stm32l1xx_hal::gpio::GpioExt;
   use stm32l1xx_hal::hal::digital::v2::OutputPin;
   use stm32l1xx_hal::rcc::{Config, RccExt};
   use stm32l1xx_hal::stm32::Peripherals;
   use stm32l1xx_hal::stm32::CorePeripherals;
   use stm32l1xx_hal::time::MicroSeconds;


   #[entry]
   fn main() -> ! {

       let p = Peripherals::take().unwrap();
       let cp = CorePeripherals::take().unwrap();

       // Get LED pin PB6
       let gpiob = p.GPIOB.split();
       let mut led = gpiob.pb6.into_push_pull_output();

       // Set up a delay
       let rcc = p.RCC.freeze(Config::default());
       let mut delay = Delay::new(cp.SYST, rcc.clocks);

       loop {

           // Turn LED On
           led.set_high().unwrap();

           delay.delay(MicroSeconds(1_000_000_u32));

           // Turn LED Off
           led.set_low().unwrap();

           delay.delay(MicroSeconds(1_000_000_u32));
       }
   }
   ```

- For me, the key was to understand that the `split` method can be called from the `Peripherals` because `stm32l1xx-hal` implemented `split` for a struct defined in `stm32l1`. In other words, the HAL crate is not only defining new structs, but also extending functionality for existing structs. I need to wrap my head around trait design patterns.